# How do I improve this slow count query on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I'm at a lost here. We have this query which takes around 50s to finish which I think it's too slow. Here's the query. We use MySQL from Amazon RDS running on `db.r3.large` and MySQL version `MySQL 5.7.17`

```
SELECT bucket_label            AS bid, 
       Count(user_id)          AS c, 
       Count(DISTINCT user_id) AS cu 
FROM   event_impression 
WHERE  context = 'PROD' 
       AND experiment_id = Unhex(Replace("18454a99-ada6-41a8-b192-bcd3d5c514cb", 
                                 "-", 
                                 "")) 
       AND timestamp >= '2018-04-08 22:21:04' 
       AND timestamp <= '2018-04-10 22:21:04' 
GROUP  BY bucket_label;
```

Here are the indexes

```
mysql> show index from event_impression;
+------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| event_impression |          1 | user_id                 |            1 | user_id       | A         |     3248866 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | experiment_id           |            1 | experiment_id | A         |        4305 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | bucket_label            |            1 | bucket_label  | A         |        7108 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | timestamp               |            1 | timestamp     | A         |     3315621 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | event_impression_ibfk_1 |            1 | experiment_id | A         |        2914 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | event_impression_ibfk_1 |            2 | bucket_label  | A         |        9619 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here's the table schema

```
mysql> describe event_impression;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id       | varchar(200)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| experiment_id | varbinary(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| bucket_label  | varchar(64)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| timestamp     | datetime      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| payload       | varchar(4096) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| context       | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | PROD    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And here's the result of that query

```
mysql> select bucket_label as bid,
    -> count(user_id) as c,
    -> count(distinct user_id) as cu
    -> from wasabi.event_impression
    -> where context = 'PROD'
    -> and experiment_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("18454a99-ada6-41a8-b192-bcd3d5c514cb", "-",""))
    -> and timestamp >= '2018-04-08 22:21:04'
    -> and timestamp <= '2018-04-10 22:21:04'
    -> group by bucket_label;
+---------+--------+-------+
| bid     | c      | cu    |
+---------+--------+-------+
| 1       | 294308 | 22403 |
| 1_1     | 185561 | 14703 |
| 2_1     | 267417 | 22183 |
| 2_2     | 284134 | 21945 |
+---------+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (41.22 sec)
```

I'm open to any suggestions to improve this query. Or if you want to see any settings also please let me know.

This is how big the table is

```
mysql> select count(*) from event_impression;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 40955148 |
+----------+
1 row in set (10.88 sec)
```

This is the `EXPLAIN`

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows     | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | event_impression | NULL       | ref  | experiment_id,bucket_label,timestamp,event_impression_ibfk_1 | event_impression_ibfk_1 | 18      | const | 14958978 |     1.43 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.16 sec)
```

EDIT

```
explain select bucket_label as bid, 
count(user_id) as c, 
count(distinct user_id) as cu
from wasabi.event_impression
where context = 'PROD' 
and experiment_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("18454a99-ada6-41a8-b192-bcd3d5c514cb", "-",""))
and timestamp >= '2018-04-08 22:21:04'
and timestamp <= '2018-04-10 22:21:04'
group by bucket_label;

'1', 'SIMPLE', 'event_impression', NULL, 'ref', 'experiment_id,bucket_label,timestamp,event_impression_ibfk_1', 'event_impression_ibfk_1', '18', 'const', '14551230', '1.32', 'Using index condition; Using where'
```

**EDIT**

Switch the where statement to have timestamp at the beginning.

```
explain select bucket_label as bid, 
count(user_id) as c, 
count(distinct user_id) as cu
from wasabi.event_impression
where timestamp BETWEEN '2018-04-08 22:21:04' AND '2018-04-10 22:21:04'
AND context = 'PROD'
AND experiment_id = UNHEX(REPLACE("18454a99-ada6-41a8-b192-bcd3d5c514cb", "-",""))
group by bucket_label;

+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows     | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | event_impression | NULL       | ref  | experiment_id,bucket_label,timestamp,event_impression_ibfk_1 | event_impression_ibfk_1 | 18      | const | 16274608 |     1.22 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+


mysql> show index from wasabi.event_impression;
+------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| event_impression |          1 | user_id                 |            1 | user_id       | A         |     3836266 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | experiment_id           |            1 | experiment_id | A         |        5083 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | bucket_label            |            1 | bucket_label  | A         |        8393 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | timestamp               |            1 | timestamp     | A         |     3915091 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | event_impression_ibfk_1 |            1 | experiment_id | A         |        3441 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_impression |          1 | event_impression_ibfk_1 |            2 | bucket_label  | A         |       11358 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: How big is the table? Try an index on `(context, experiment_id, timestamp, bucket, user_id)`

Comment: We have the indexes on those columns already.

Comment: I'm updating to see how big the table is

Comment: What was the query plan?

Comment: I updated the question with EXPLAIN

Comment: I meant a single composite index, not 5.

Comment: what is query plan saying ? Create single composite index like ypercube is saying. I think most selective column should be in left and so on.So if timestamp is most selective i.e will produce least row then timestamp should be first in bracket and so on.

Comment: Ah sorry I will update the indexes and comment it again.

Comment: I tried dropping all the indexes and created just one composite index, it was 25% faster.

Comment: @toy In your original question, after the show index from event_impression;  post the CURRENT RESULTS as of mm-dd-ccyy so we can see your current index definition.

Comment: @toy consider this slight rearrangement of query WHERE clause and post EXPLAIN for my suggestion, please.

SELECT bucket_label            AS bid, 
       Count(user_id)          AS c, 
       Count(DISTINCT user_id) AS cu 
FROM   event_impression 
WHERE
       timestamp BETWEEN '2018-04-08 22:21:04' AND '2018-04-10 22:21:04'
       AND  
           context = 'PROD' 
       AND experiment_id = Unhex(Replace("18454a99-ada6-41a8-b192-bcd3d5c514cb", 
                                 "-", 
                                 "")) 
       GROUP  BY bucket_label;

    Not tested.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I edited the question I think it's still looking for `event_impression_ibfk_1` which I think that's the problem here.

Comment: @toy Please post the new EXPLAIN results in your original question after older EXPLAIN.  And SHOW INDEX FROM event_impression;  please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added the EXAPLIN.

Comment: @toy - `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: @KumarHarsh - "Selectivity"/"cardinality" is irrelevant when ordering the columns in an index.  (It's an old 'wives tale' with no basis.)

Comment: @WilsonHauck - rearranging `ANDs` in `WHERE` has _no_ impact on optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Start an index with `=` parts of the `WHERE`, then add one "range" on:

```
INDEX(context, experiment_id,   -- in either order
      timestamp)
```

That will make the query run faster.

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on creating optimal indexes.

Note:  a 'composite' index is not the same as having multiple single-column indexes.

A "covering" index would be bulky, but make it run a somewhat faster:

```
INDEX(context, experiment_id,   -- in either order
      timestamp,
      bucket_label, user_id)    -- in either order
```

**Do *not* put `timestamp` first.**

Index usage works from left to right.  Scanning for rows will do what it can with the first column in the index, then move on to the next.

If the first column is tested with `=` (eg, `context = 'PROD'`), the *all* the rows in the index that match that are adjacent, and the next column can be useful.

If the first column is tested with a 'range' (eg, `timestamp BETWEEN ... AND ...`), the next column becomes useless.  So the Optimizer stops at the first range.

A familiar example...  Suppose there is a list of people, sorted by lastname first.  And we want to find 'Dave Poole'.

```
INDEX(last, first)
```

I suspect there is little quibble with

```
WHERE first = 'Dave'
  AND last  = 'Poole'   -- (in either order)
```

But now, what if the query is

```
WHERE first LIKE 'D%'   -- (this is one form of "range")
  AND last = 'Poole'
```

This turns out to be efficient -- Drill down the BTree to the long list of 'Pooles' to where the D's are, then scan forward.

On the other hand, what about

```
WHERE first = 'Dave'
  AND last LIKE 'P%'
```

Now how do you find the entries?  Well, you can quickly drill down the BTree to where P... starts, but you must scan *all* of the entries with last name starting with P.  There is more efficient way than that.

(Of course, having `INDEX(first, last)` would be efficient.)

As for selectiveness / cardinality...

- Searching for Poole+Dave is very selective -- it is the combination of both.  The BTree does not Poole, then Dave; it does both at the same time.
- Searching for Poole+D% is also the combined selectiveness of pair, which is more than either `last` or `first`.
- Searching for P%+... can only use the selectiveness of the "P" in `last`, hence the worst case.

So, starting with 2018... (`timestamp`) is worse than PROD+abcd+2018 (the index I recommended).

Comment: Why would you not put timestamp first?  Surely this would be the most selective combination.  I could understand the comment in the context of a column store where column store compression makes the least selective column the most important but InnoDB isn't a column store.

Comment: @DavePoole - I added to my Answer

Comment: I can see how the timestamp would be less selective if it was treated as a string but under the hood a timestamp is a numeric type.  Do InnoDB multi-field indexes get concatenated into a single data attribute of type string?

Comment: @DavePoole - Date-like datatypes are numeric, and are (probably) compared as unsigned ints.  A composite index with both a numeric and a string will not literally "concatenate", but you could think if it that way.  Float/double must be compared in a third way.  Collation adds a serious complication to string compares (think of case folding), making a simple comparison of bytes impossible (unless collation is *_bin).  Etc. (signed/unsigned, etc)

Comment: OK, if this was SQL Server the timestamp would be stored as a fixed precision number with the date represented as the integer part and time as the decimal part.  If InnoDB takes the same approach then this contradicts the assertion that starting with timestamp is worse.  It isn't a bunch of similar strings its a bunch of different numbers.

Comment: @DavePoole - I suspect SQL Server also handles indexes left-to-right.  What I describe applies at least to MySQL.  MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` is a numeric value; so is (as you point out) SQLServer's.  OK, the details of how it is stored may matter, but still there are rules for comparing two values.  And those rules _probably_ prevent playing the "concatenate" trick.

Comment: @DavePoole - The number format is not the issue; processing an index left-to-right ordering is the issue.  (Think about lastname versus firstname in an ordered list of people.)

Comment: The subject is event impressions.  The figures supplied in the question show the timestamp column to be THE most selective column, both context and experiment_id have low selectivity.  Certainly in SQL Server the query optimiser can choose to ignore an index if the selectivity is low. This is why I believe timestamp first is correct.  The only way.  The only way to resolve this discussion is to generate the sample data and perform the experiment.

Comment: @DavePoole - Rather than try to squeeze a reply into a Comment, or even add to my Answer, I wrote a specific Q&A:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/should-i-put-the-higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-ra

Answer (score 1):

The higher the cardinality the more selective the index is.
event_impression_ibfk_1 is being used on experiment_id and bucket_label neither of which appear to be particularly selective.

If I am reading the explain plan correctly it thinks it needs to scan 14.9 million or your 40 million row table.  If you have some quiet time or preferably downtime available it might be worth running

```
ANALYZE TABLE event_impression
```

This is to ensure the distribution statistics of your table are up-to-date and thus help the query optimiser.
Make sure you have physical resources for such a command to run, it will hit CPU and disk quite hard

Is there some combination of fields in your table that are unique?  If so then this will cause the InnoDB engine to use it to create the clustered index for the table.  Clustered indexes are very fast when it comes to range scans which will play to your advantage if one of those fields that make up uniqueness is timestamp.  A table can only ever have one clustered index.  In MySQL the precedence for the DB Engine creating a clustered index is as follows:-

- Primary key
- Unique key
- Synthetic key consisting of the internal row id

Failing that try putting an index across timestamp, experiment_id and bucket_label.  Again, you had best do this in quiet/down time and make sure you have the physical resource available to do it.

On a separate point be very careful using field names that are reserved words such as timestamp.  You can get some peculiar exceptions thrown in applications that are very hard to track down.

Comment: Cardinality is irrelevant.  `ANALYZE` is rarely useful for InnoDB tables.  Fixing the `INDEX` is more useful than 'throwing hardware at the problem'.  Having a PK is good, but not relevant to speeding up the query.

Answer (score 0):

event_impression has NO PRIMARY key according to SHOW INDEX FROM event_impression.  My guess in looking at Cardinality numbers, after your table columnname of timestamp is Altered to a non-reserved word for columnname, such as e_i_timestamp, you could use e_i_timestamp, user_id as a composite Primary Key for the table.  Net result of having planned PRIMARY KEY is usually smaller table size in INNODB and a more efficient table for your 40M rows.

Comment: Yes, having an explicit PK is a good idea for InnoDB tables.  However, any form of datetime/timestamp is risky -- unless you can 'guarantee' never creating two rows in the same second.